# What measures prevent a military aircraft's weapons from being fired on the ground?

Tags: safety, military

Recently the 20mm cannon of an F-16 was accidentally fired on the ground by maintenance personnel at Florennes Air Base in Belgium, resulting the the destruction of another F-16 and damage to a third.

https://theaviationist.com/2018/10/14/f-16-completely-destroyed-by-another-f-16-after-mechanic-accidentally-fires-cannon-on-the-ground-in-belgium/

What measures do  military aircraft have to prevent their weapons from being fired while the plane is on ground?

Answer (score 11):

Normally with aircraft there is a sensor called a weight on wheels switch.  This tells the computer that the aircraft is on the ground.  The computer (or a system of relays for older air frames) will prevent any system that was designated by the owner, or required by regulations, from activating while in the ground.  Also as a secondary preventative measure certain mechanical systems are also pinned in place after landing to help prevent ground actuation.  However if it happened during maintenance it is very likely these systems were disabled to perform system maintenance on the cannon.

Comment: Your answer is far better than mine. Still begs the question - why were they doing maintenance on an _armed_ aircraft?? That, however, is a different question.

Comment: But do you actually know whether weapon arming is tied to the squat switch on fighters? It would be somewhat unexpected.

Answer (score 5):

The article quoted implies that there is a sensor in the F16 to detect when the undercarriage is lowered, which functions as a a gun safety switch, but there is presumably provision for overriding this in order to perform gun testing.
A variety of technical and procedural measures are designed to ensure safety with aircraft gun armament, the details varying with the specific type of weapon. The M61 20mm cannon will not function without electrical power, it is electrically rotated (when internally mounted) and fires electrically primed ammunition, so switching off the power should prevent accidental firing with this gun. Other types of cannon with reciprocating mechanisms, such as the 30mm DEFA 550 series have to be cocked or armed before they will fire, a common procedure is to prohibit pilots from doing this until the aircraft is airborne.

Comment: What, you can't test a gun in flight?

Comment: It would be less expensive and quicker to test it on the ground if possible.

Answer (score 4):

There are also physical safety switches, that date back to when weapons were first mounted on aircraft. Still present on modern armed aircraft. On the F16, a switch on the joystick controls selection of missiles or gun. One of it's positions is 'safe'. Obviously, that switch on the Belgian F16 wasn't in the safe position.

During WW2, there was a real problem with aircraft landing on a carrier, and the guns being discharged accidentally when the jolt of the landing and arresting caused the pilot's hand to hit the trigger on the joystick. Consequently, landing on a carrier with the gun switch not in the safe position was a serious transgression that would land a pilot in real trouble... you could kill a lot of deck crew if you discharged six .50 cal machine guns across the deck.

Even so, accidents can happen. On July 29, 1967, the USS Forrestal was seriously damaged when [a Zuni air to ground missile was accidentally discharged](https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history/rocket-causes-deadly-fire-on-aircraft-carrier) from an F4 Phantom, striking an A4 Skyhawk waiting to take off. Piloting that Skyhawk was a young navy Lt, John S McCain. While the missile didn't detonate, it did tear open the Skyhawk's fuel tanks, starting a major fire, which led to a 1000 pound bomb detonating. 134 sailors died as a result, and hundreds were injured. It is believed that a short circuit of the firing mechanism led to the missile being discharged.

Aircraft carriers in particular can be quite dangerous. They combine high performance aircraft, high speed takeoffs and landings, plus all the fuel and munitions that the aircraft will carry, in a fairly small space. The fact that aircraft carriers don't blow up more often is a testament to the quality and discipline of it's crew.

Since the Forrestal incident, there have been no repeats of missiles being accidentally discharged on a carrier deck. Whatever measures were put in place after that, appear to have been effective.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, for the F-16 to fire the gun on the ground you need, Ammo, electrical and hydraulic power, hold back tool removed, electrical safety pin removed, rounds limiter set to off or at least 100. No avionics need be powered. Master arm to arm, ground Jett to enable. Squeeze the trigger. The gun will fire until the last round switch opens because it’s out of ammo, the rounds counter if set to on hits zero, the security police shoot the guy sitting in the cockpit.

The Belgium accident had 2 major Tech Order violations.

1. ammunition installed during gun operational check. Without ammo, a technician will need to hold the last round bypass switch to on. FWIW that switch is just forward of the gun housing so if someone was holding it they are most likely deaf and or burned pretty bad.
2. gun holdback clearing tool installed and gun rotated to clear rounds from the firing cycle.

It’s been 30 years since I did my last F-16 gun ops check and I still remember how to do it and not get killed or shoot the place up.

Also to correct some other posts. The gun is electrically controlled and fired. It is rotated by a hydraulically powered motor.

Comment: You say having ammo was a tech order violation, but then you say *without ammo* manually holding the switch is dangerous, so what is the correct way? Thanks and welcome to the site.

Comment: @ymb1: Manually holding the switch is dangerous _with_ ammo, because the holder would be right next to the firing gun.  No ammo = no firing = not dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

The gun would not have been fired by accident. The mistake here is that they did not unload all live munitions to make the aircraft safe before functionally testing the weapons system. There are multiple safety interlocks that stop a gun from “just firing”.

1. The undercarriage being down and locked or weight on wheels (WoW) is the first.
2. There will be a Master Armament Safety Switch that stops the armament control system from being powered. (It will have to be set to live during testing and when releasing stores in anger or jettisoning them in an emergency). (Some aircraft also have a standby position to carry out self testing prior to flight).
3. the guns selected on the weapon control panel.
4. a switch called a late arm switch set on.
5. then the trigger depressed.
6. In modern aircraft navigation/weapons computers also have to be turned on and a target has to be selected before a commit to fire signal gets passed to the gun/store.
7. some gun tests also require the gun to actually be electrically disconnected and a test box connected in its place with LED’s to show the gun firing pulse is being received.

To fire on the ground WoW override tools would be used, some aircraft have BUTTS switches or armament ground test switches to trick the computers into thinking the aircraft is in flight. The aircraft nav computers will need to be turned on with potentially a dummy flight plan loaded.

Comment: You seem to know your stuff and this is a good answer, except for that first sentence.  I understand you mean that there are many steps required and the gun couldn't simply "go off", but if you read the sentence by itself it implies that the actual discharge of bullets was intentional.  But of course, it was fired by accident.

Answer (score 1):

According to the article you linked:

> the use of the onboard weapons (including the gun) is usually blocked by a fail-safe switch when the aircraft has the gear down with the purpose of preventing similar accidents.

It seems it isn't quite so "fail" or "safe", at least in this instance.

Comment: It seems more like fail-to-safe.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of fighters have some kind of a "Master Arm" switch that brings the weapons live as well as activates some other related functionality. As [discussed by this former F-15 pilot in the podcast ***224 – Flying the F-15 Eagle***](http://omegataupodcast.net/224-flying-the-f-15-eagle/) its flown in the off position *99% of the time*. There is also some discussion about [HUD functionality related to the master arm options in this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/hoggit/comments/4rxdo0/why_do_f16_pilots_fly_with_master_arm_to_sim/) (but its Reddit so take it with a grain of salt).

[In this article about refueling the F-15](https://fightersweep.com/2387/from-the-cockpit-nasa-f-15d-refueling/)

> As the fighters approach, they will be asked to “check nose cold and
> switches safe.” That simply means that all emitters are off, to
> include the IFF system, any ECM pods, and the radar is placed in
> standby mode. If the approaching receivers were in a fight prior to
> the rejoin, ***it’s critical for them to have their Master Arm switch to
> the OFF position and thereby safing any remaining stores aboard***.

Depending on the airframe, they may slo simply unload the ordinance to prevent accidental discharge.

Comment: Depending on the platform, the master arm switch may also disable all high-power EM transmitters as well as countermeasures. But again, depending on platform, there may be a ground override switch to bypass weight-on-wheels to allow master arm to be enabled on the ground =/